# undefined method while using form_for in New controller method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Im getting this error on rendering the form for New controller method:

undefined method `teacher_id' for #
Extracted source (around line #8):

```
 <table summary="Student form fields">
  <tr>
    <th>Teacher ID</th>
    <td><%= f.number_field :teacher_id %></td>  # this is line 8
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Parent ID</th>
```

This is new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add A Student</h1>

<%= form_for @student, :url => { :action => 'create'}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<table summary="Student form fields">
   <tr>
     <th>Teacher ID</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :teacher_id %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Parent ID</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :parent_id %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>FirstName</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :firstname %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>LastName</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :lastname %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Date of Birth</th>
     <td><%= f.date_field :dob %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Email</th>
     <td><%= f.email_field :email %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Cellphone</th>
     <td><%= f.telephone_field :cellphone %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Username</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :username %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Password</th>
     <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Confirm Password</th>
     <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Address Street#</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_streetno %></td>
     <th>Apt #</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :addr_aptno %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>City</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_city %></td>
     <th>State</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_state %></td>
     <th>Zip</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :addr_zip %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Photo</th>
     <td><%= f.file_field :photo %></td>
   </tr>
</table>

   <%= f.submit 'Create Student' %>
<% end %>

<% if @student.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @student.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

'This is the student.rb model file:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    #attr_accessor :teacherid, :firstname, :lastname, :dob, :isadult, 
    #              :email, :cellphone, :username, :password, :addr_streetno, 
    #             :addr_city, :addr_state, :addr_zip, :photo

    #has_secure_password

    belongs_to :parent
    belongs_to :teacher

    attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates_confirmation_of :password

    scope :sorted, lambda { order("students.firstname ASC")}
end
```

This is the structure of the student table:

```
create_table :students do |t|
   t.references :parents
   t.references :teachers, null: false

   t.string :firstname, null: false
   t.string :lastname, null: false
   t.date :dob, null: false
   t.boolean :isadult, null: false, default: false
   t.string :email, null: false
   t.string :cellphone
   t.string :username, null: false
   t.string :password_digest, null: false
   t.string :addr_streetno
   t.integer :addr_aptno
   t.string :addr_city
   t.string :addr_state
   t.integer :addr_zip
   t.binary :photo, :limit => 0.5.megabyte

   t.timestamps
 end
```

Comment: Im unable to understand why RoR thinks that @student.teacher_id is a method. Is this a problem with the syntax that I am using with form_for construct. Earlier, I had the form_tag construct and just adapted it with minimal change for form_for construct.

Comment: Please let me know what is the issue in the code or whether I need to change my approach. @Wali Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table definition says `teachers` where it should be `teacher`, since it’s a `belongs_to`. It should read this way:

```
t.references :parent
t.references :teacher, null: false
```

Comment: so it doesnt matter if the name of the FK table was actually parents or teachers? I thought it was referring to the name of the FK tables. But is the singular and plural decided by whether its a belongs_to at the student table. In the teacher model, I have a has_many: students

Comment: The Rails/ActiveRecord convention is that the parent model `has_many :children` but the child only `belongs_to :parent`.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to ask that the student table migration file should have t.references :parent even if the the parent table is actually plural (parents) in its own migration file?

Comment: Yes, the convention is that table names are pluralised. But a student only references their `parent` and `teacher`, since in your setup, they only have one.

Comment: the fix worked in rendering the form. This was a key learning for me. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

`Buck Doyle`'s answer is right, however, to expand on it, I would mention that when you receive a `no method` error - it means your `object` does not have the attributes you're calling

--

**Attributes**

You have to remember everything in Ruby is an `object`, which Rails populates with a series of `attributes`. Although we call them `attributes` in Rails, the fact is every object (created with a `Rails Model` / `Ruby Class`) has a series of `methods` which are called each time you have an instance of it

Therefore, if you have a `model`, what you're really doing is defining the `attributes` / `methods` which Rails is able to call. That's why you can use virtual attributes with [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) - this tells the `model` (a `Ruby class`) to include those methods

Simply, your `ActiveRecord` objects will always be populated with attributes from your database, as well as any virtual attributes you set. The `no method` error means you're trying to call attributes which don't exist

--

**Fix**

The way to fix a `no method` error is to ensure you have the correct columns in your db

As highlighted by `Buck Doyle`, the most likely issue you have is you've referenced `t.references :teachers, null: false` in your migration, which it should be singular

Comment: Rich, thanks for yours and Buck Doyle's responses. It was indeed the case. I had to redo the db migrations after fixing the t.references :parent & t.references :teacher in the student table migration file. Now the http://localhost:3000/student/new url shows up the form. Whether or not, it will save the data that it gets in the form is another matter. I will open another issue for such issues.